react-native google places autocomplete not working for expo
some months ago I worked with react-native-google-places-autocomplete and I did not encounter any issue but now I am trying to add some updates to the project and discover that it's no longer working when I run the app and causes my app to crash with this error
crypto.getRandomValues() not supported. See https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid#getrandomvalues-not-supported
this is the version installed
"react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^2.5.7",

and this is how I use it in my code
import tw from 'tailwind-react-native-classnames'

import { GooglePlacesAutocomplete } from 'react-native-google-places-autocomplete'

  return (
<SafeAreaView style={tw`bg-white flex-1 ` }>
  
  <View style={tw`border-t border-gray-200 flex-shrink`}>

        
        <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
        placeholder='Move To?'
        styles={toolInputBoxStyle}
        fetchDetails={true}
        returnKeyType={'search'}
        minLength={2}
        listViewDisplayed= 'auto'
        onPress={(data, details = null) => {
            dispatch(setDestination({
                location: details.geometry.location,
                description: data.description,
            }))
            navigation.navigate('NextPage')
        }}
        enablePoweredByContainer={false}
        query={{
            key: GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY,
            language: 'en'
        }
        }
        nearbyPlacesAPI='GooglePlacesSearch' 
        debounce={400}
         />
    
  </View>
</SafeAreaView>

)
}

I am using "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^2.5.6"
Run npm install --save react-native-get-random-values
Then simple go to your project index file and import below line on yop of your function.

import 'react-native-get-random-values'

run npm start and it is working for both android and IOS

I was getting the same error and your solution worked for me. Thanks.
